# Assign Build - Available builds is disabled in Microsoft Test Manager

Tags: mtm

I have created sample Coded UI Test in VS15 and checked in to the TFS15. Made a build definition using XAML and associate test there. 
At MTM frount, I have ready environment with Test controller and agent. Plan and Test tasks are also completed in MTM Testing Center but When I move to Track in Assign Build to assign build I see Available builds drop down is disabled when i refresh i got below error message looking for help on this matter.
I am using Test Controller and Test Agent version 2013.

Application detected an unexpected fault.

> Could not load type
>   'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.WebApi.QueryDeletedOption' from
>   assembly 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build2.WebApi, Version=14.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.

Answer (score 0):

Have u tried running MTM on a different machine, maybe your MTM installation was not succesful.

Try that and let me know.

Pablo

Comment: Thanks for your reply pablo, I will sure check with MTM at different machine  / Reinstall of MTM and let you know.